# Why does adding a routerlink mess up the style?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a navigation menu where you hit a div and that div expands to links you can hit to navigate around the application. It would basically look something like this:

[image: sanp]

the 'test2' links are now in the 'expanded' state revealing the clickable links to navigate. The 'test3' links are in the collapsable state. But if I were to click 'test3', 'test3' would expand to show its links and 'test2' would collapse. I wanted to have an animation that collapses/expands. So, to do that, the current outline of the code looks like:

```
<div class="container" (click)="expand()" [ngClass]="{'expand': ...}">
   <div class="container-header">
     test2
   </div>
   <div class="container-links">
     <div *ngFor="let link of links">{{link}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
.container{
  height: 61px
  overflow: hidden
  .container-header{
    height: 61px;
  }
  &.expand{
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

So I basically purposely overflow the container div, and when the user clicks it, the height gets set to auto to let it expand and reveal the links.

That all works fine. The issue is appears whenever I add a `[routerLink]` to the links in the `for` loop. When that happens, for whatever reason, this happens:

[image: sanp]

The 'test2' header piece gets pushed up and the 'test' link just shows. It seems like that `routerLink` is moving the header out of the way so that it can be exposed.
All I changed to the above code is:

```
<div class="container" (click)="expand()" [ngClass]="{'expand': ...}">
   <div class="container-header">
     test2
   </div>
   <div class="container-links">
     <div *ngFor="let link of links" [routerLink]="">{{link}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and for some reason it's doing that. I have no idea why. Been struggling with this one all day.

Answer (score 0):

Try use anchor links for the routerLink instead of div.
And you might consider using ul and li.